# Division by zero error in Erdas imagine 2014

Tags: erdas-imagine

I'm running a Model maker to divide a couple of rasters. The function is as follows:

```
($n1_band1 / $n2_band2)* 100
```

There is no zero in both images (both of them are integers). However, I'm still getting the division by zero error.

Anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Its likely a bug. Have you asked Intergraph?